# Disable ClearType fonts in Windows8

Tags: fonts, cleartype, truetype, windows-8-fonts

How is it possible completely disable ClearType fonts in Windows 8. Fonts really look very ugly on my Windows 8. I tried disable via cttune.exe but it doesn't help.

Thanks!

Comment: You should provide a screenshot.  They look fine on my Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

this should help: 
http://www.wikihow.com/Adjust-Cleartype-Text-in-Windows-8

Hope That Helps!

Comment: Hi Paul, welcome to SU!  Link-only answers are considered a no-no due to possible future link-rot.  Please include pertinent information in your answers, and link to the source.